# how to write Request Payload using flurl

Tags: c#, json, payload, flurl

how to write **Request Payload** using **Flurl**, I only know the general form of writing.

example payload:

```
text1:xxx
text2:1
```

code on flurl :

```
PostJsonAsync(New
{
   text1= "xxx",
   text2 = 1
});
```

how to write json to flurl if the payload is like this

```
text1:[]
text2:"{"refer_urls":[]}"
```

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `PostStringAsync` instead of `PostJsonAsync`. This skips the JSON serialization step and allows you to specify the precise string you want to send, which is what you want here since the payload as a whole is not valid JSON.